# Australian Tourist Visa Payment Dispute

Tags: transit-visas, australia, tourist-visas

I Applied for Australian Tourist Visa and paid the fee and while waiting to get an approval, i learned that I can just do Transit visa since I'm only staying there for 2.5 days from a cruise trip. I got both approval for tourist and transit and then I called to cancel my tourist before my trip and the fee returned to my credit card. I am thinking i can use the transit visa. After 3months, Australian visa emailed me that I need to repay them back for the tourist visa that i used because they said it was automatically ceased my transit since they approved my tourist.

My question is, can i just ignore this and not pay it or am I going to have trouble here in the US where I reside? They said if i didn't pay, it will go to debtors section in their National Headquarters and will result having a debt to the commonwealth. Waht will happen if I don't and im not planning to go back there.

Comment: Let us get this straight - you applied for a tourist visa and it was granted, then you cancelled your visa and got a refund, then you entered Australia (not sure how?), and now Australia says you need to repay them for the visa that you *did* use even though you said you weren't going to. Is that accurate?

Comment: For clarity, could you please edit your question to state the fees you paid and the fee(s) you were refunded? It’s not entirely clear from your question whether they refunded your transit visa fee when it was ceased after granting your tourist visa.

Comment: @GregHewgill If I'm parsing that right, the OP paid for and received two visas, one transit, one tourist.  Intending to use the transit visa, they got a refund for the tourist visa and assumed it was cancelled.  However, apparently their entry into Australia recorded under the tourist visa, not the transit visa, and now Australia wants to charge her again for it!

Answer (score 2):

So, if I have this correct, you applied for two visas, paid the fee(s) and got both approved.

Somehow, you got a refund for one. I'd guess this is the mistake of Australian Immigration. Now they are saying you should pay them. Australian Immigration have done the work, so morally you owe them the money.

I doubt they'll coming banging in your door in the US. However, if you leave it unpaid it could result in you being stopped at immigration if you visit Australia again.

Perhaps more pertinent is the possibility that they'll notify any credit reference agencies they deal with. Credit reference agencies work internationally, so an unpaid debt could bite you from an unexpected direction in the US.